# iPhone 4 iOS 6.1.2 Keyboard -> Shortcuts not working properly

Tags: keyboard, iphone, ios, settings

It was all working fine till I was on 6.1, I upgraded to 6.1.2 and restored my backup from  iTunes after which I noticed that the text-expander is not working. for e.g. when I type "omw" it doesn't get expanded to "On my way!"

I tried a lot, reset (Home + Power), installed Xpander2 from Cydia, etc etc.

I again restored the iOS but did NOT restore old backup this time and started fresh setup. But its still not working.

Any idea guys? what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I managed to fix it by simply installing "Manual Correct" from Cydia. Configured all the text expander shortcuts into it, and I got what I wanted.

Still the problem with iOS built-in shortcut is not resolved. But I don't need that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was working fine in 6.1.1 until i update to 6.1.2. I later found my itunes backup restore cleared all my shortcuts so i had to enter them again. Shortcuts worked well for a while and now don't work anymore.

Comment: Exactly, As soon as I close the settings and reopen it, All my shortcuts are gone again. Its like settings is not actually writing/saving them permanently.

Comment: I finally gave up and used "manual correct" tweak from Cydia as I have mentioned in my answer.